# What is meant by the phrase adapter/connector?

Tags: adapter, connector, sailpoint

This is a basic questions. I want to apply to an entry level java developer position with the following requirement:

Familiarity with the Sailpoint Identity IQ standard adapters/connectors

By standard connectors do they basically mean how Sailpoint exchanges data with third party tools? And by adapter do they mean that the adapter pattern would be used? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is going to probably appear well after your interview - but to answer the question:

1) Standard adapters/connectors:
    SailPoint ships with a "standard" set of connectors which are part of the purchase price there are those ie EPIC which do not ship as part of the standard product and must be enabled. To give you a deeper view into connectors..

Connectivity Methods:

Direct Connectivity - This is where a connector communicates directly to a system using APIs or data-sources. Some advantages of using direct connect are that you don't have to generate or transmit files, and you can be more efficient in processing only things that have changed. Some disadvantages are the they are subject to availability and downtime concerns like any connected system. They are also typically subject to advantages and disadvantages that APIs might impose as well.
Some people also refer to this as an 'online' method of connectivity.

File-Based Connectivity - This is where a connector reads from a snapshot of data presented in a file, rather than connecting directly to the system. Some advantages of using a file, are that files are portable, easily inspected for data issues, and not typically subject to availability. Some disadvantages are that files are usually processed in their entirety, and may require processing or transformation in order to work effectively.
Some people also refer to this as a 'decoupled' or 'offline' method of connectivity.
Connector Implementations

Source-Specific Implementation - These are connectors built with a specific target-system in mind. These typically use specific APIs targeted to the system they are integrated with. Because the systems and APIs are known, these typically require less configurations to get working.
Examples of these are Active Directory, Workday, Salesforce, SAP, etc.

General Implementation - These are general-purpose connectors which can be used to connect to a variety of sources or systems. These tend to be more flexible in general, but typically do require a bit more setup and configuration to meet needs.
Examples of these are Web Services, SCIM, JDBC, Delimited Files, etc.

Custom Implementation - These are completely custom connectors and tailored to the system and API of your choice. This approach offers the most flexibility of all connector options, however making custom connectors is definitely a development-level activity, and is not to be taken lightly. The code written for custom connectors is maintained and supported by the customer who owns the connector.
Examples of these are custom in-house applications, etc.

Understanding these connector implementations is important, because if a source-specific implementation isn't available, another general or custom connector implementation may be used instead.